# How to show only part of model in QTreeView?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtreeview

I've been playing around with [this](https://gist.github.com/skriticos/5415869) code and I don't understand, how to adjust model columns visibility.

```
for i in range(3):
    parent1 = QStandardItem('Family {}. Some long status text for sp'.format(i))
    for j in range(3):
        child1 = QStandardItem('Child {}'.format(i*3+j))
        child2 = QStandardItem('row: {}, col: {}'.format(i, j+1))
        child3 = QStandardItem('row: {}, col: {}'.format(i, j+2))
        parent1.appendRow([child1, child2, child3])
    model.appendRow(parent1)
    # span container columns
    view.setFirstColumnSpanned(i, view.rootIndex(), True)
```

I want to have one model with many fields and several views, each displaying only specific columns.
I don't want to hide columns with `setColumnHidden`, because when model gets extended, I'll have to hide new columns.

I'm familiar with Gtk and it's quite simple there: you create a `TreeView`, manually add columns, fill them with renderers and tell each renderer, from which column in model it should take data. Is it possible with Qt?

Comment: You can use a QSortFilterProxyModel to filter the data you want to hide

Comment: @Fabio thanks. Do I have to subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel` and call `filterAcceptsColumn` or there is something I miss out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a QSortFilterProxyModel:

```py
class FilterColumnModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FilterColumnModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._columns = None

    @property
    def columns(self):
        return self._columns

    @columns.setter
    def columns(self, columns):
        self._columns = columns[:]
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsColumn(self, source_column, source_parent):
        if self.columns is None:
            return True
        return source_column in self.columns
```

```
filter_model = FilterColumnModel()
filter_model.setSourceModel(model)
filter_model.columns = [0, 2]
view.setModel(filter_model)
view.setUniformRowHeights(True)
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks!